# How to Excel web query this web site when I cannot input parameter in the URL

Tags: excel, excel-web-query

The website I am trying to Excel web query is (http://www.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/search_sdw.asp). Where I need to input stock code (E.g. 1237) and press "search" button to get the search result. However parameter is not shown in the link. Is there any way I can use Excel to automate the process of capturing such data?

Comment: A **POST** request with Content-Type **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** is used to submit the form data in this page. This means you cannot use Excel Web Query. What you want can be automated in VBA. Search how to execute a POST request in VBA using **WinHttpRequest**. Use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to understand what kind of data you need to submit in the body of the request.

Comment: Thanks for showing the direction!